# What is the correct word to describe something that is like a frustum?

Tags: adjectives, mathematics

Does such a word exist? I came across this question while writing some software that used [frustums](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frustum?s=t), making certain parts of it... eh... frustumy?

Comment: A frustum-like object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frustumic* has been [used](http://www.patentbuddy.com/Patent/4993155).

A broader term is *prismoid polyhedral*, a set that includes prisms, antiprisms, pyramids, cupolas, frustums, wedges, etc. ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPrismatoid_polyhedra))